# problem Install Manopt matlab toolbox in windows 10

Tags: matlab, installation, toolbox

I try to  install  [Manopt](https://www.manopt.org/tutorial.html) matlab toolbox in windows 10. I try the website, it says.

1. Unzip and copy the whole manopt directory you just downloaded in a location of your choice, say, in /my/directory/.
2. Go to /my/directory/manopt/ at the Matlab prompt and execute importmanopt.
3. You may save this path for your next Matlab sessions (via savepath).

However, where I try their example:

```
manifold = spherefactory(100);
```

it says:

```
Undefined function or variable 'spherefactory'.
```

Is it possible to just add `manopt` in the path? I try

```
addpath('manopt');
```

which work for some other toolbox but it doesn't work for `manopt`. Is there any way to install it on window 10? Thanks

Comment: In `addpath` you need to give the full path to the files. E.g. `addpath('c:\my\manopt')`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I copy `manopt` folder and `main.m` file into a same directory. And add the `addpath('manopt');` in the beginning of `main.m` file. But it doesn't work

Comment: As I said, that is not how `addpath` works. You need to use the **full** path. Starting with `C:\ ` or whichever drive you’re on.